# Unrecognized field "pingTimeout" execiption in Redisson with 3.12.4 version

Tags: redis, redisson

I'm using Redisson library on redis connections in my java project. With 3.12.4 version, The library gives below error:

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "pingTimeout" (class org.redisson.config.SingleServerConfig), not marked as ignorable (25 known properties: "timeout", "subscriptionsPerConnection", "keepAlive", "sslKeystorePassword", "retryInterval", "retryAttempts", "idleConnectionTimeout", "sslTruststorePassword", "sslEnableEndpointIdentification", "address", "sslTruststore", "username", "connectTimeout", "subscriptionConnectionPoolSize", "password", "sslProvider", "tcpNoDelay", "connectionMinimumIdleSize", "subscriptionConnectionMinimumIdleSize", "sslKeystore", "pingConnectionInterval", "clientName", "connectionPoolSize", "database", "dnsMonitoringInterval"])
 at [Source: (StringReader); line: 3, column: 20] (through reference chain: org.redisson.config.Config["singleServerConfig"]->org.redisson.config.SingleServerConfig["pingTimeout"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:60) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:822) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:1152) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1589) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownVanilla(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1567) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:294) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:151) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:127) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:288) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:151) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4013) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3004) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
    at org.redisson.config.ConfigSupport.fromYAML(ConfigSupport.java:182) ~[redisson-3.12.4.jar:3.12.4]
    at org.redisson.config.Config.fromYAML(Config.java:632) ~[redisson-3.12.4.jar:3.12.4]
```

In the change log file, there is no line about this. What should I do? What should I change somethig? Is there any migration guide?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `pingConnectionInterval` setting instead.

Comment: I changed like you said, but now it gives Unrecognized field "reconnectionTimeout". Is there a list to learn what I should change some of parameters with? Because I think, If I find correct one for reconnectionTimeout, there will be another field.